# Build conditional graph with first axis shape is "None" in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

When at the graph building phase, suppose the tensor `x` which is a **neural network's fully connected layer**.

So assume the shape of `x` is `(?, 5)`. I want to set the last column like this in python:

```
for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    if x[i,-1] < 0.5:
        x[i,-1] = 0.0
    else:
        x[i,-1] = 1.0
```

I can only use `tf.cond` when `x` only has 1 row like this:

```
# const3 and const4 are constant mask
out = tf.cond(tf.greater(out[-1], tf.constant(0.5)),
              lambda: tf.add(tf.multiply(out, const3), const4),
              lambda: tf.multiply(out, const3))
```

How can I check above when first dimension of `x`  is `?`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

a = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, 5])

r, c = a.get_shape()
x_split = tf.split(1, c, a) # split a along axis 1
last_col = x_split[-1]


mask = tf.greater(last_col, tf.constant(6))
cond = tf.where(mask,
                tf.add(last_col, tf.constant(1)), # if true, add one
                tf.add(last_col, tf.constant(-1)))# if false, minus one

x_split = x_split[0:-1]
x_split.append(cond)
ans = tf.concat(1, x_split)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                    [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]])
    the_ans = sess.run(ans, feed_dict={a: arr})
'''
the_ans is 
[[ 1  2  3  4  4]
 [ 6  7  8  9 11]]
'''
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, this is what i am looking for :-)